# Clearing DIV tag is not working out

Tags: javascript, css, html, charts

Hello I want to show two charts in a page using chart container. But I am unable to clear the DIV tag. So only the last chart is showing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var dataSource =
            [
                { status: "Placed", outsideindia: 6.7, india: 28.6 },
                { status: "Unplaced", unplaced: 9.6 }
            ];

        $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            commonSeriesSettings: {
                argumentField: "status",
                type: "stackedBar"
            }
        });
    });

</script>



<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 440px;"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#chartContainer").dxChart({


                series: {
                    argumentField: "st_status",
                    valueField: "oranges",
                    name: "Series 1",
                    type: "bar",
                    color: "blue"
                }
            });
        });
 </script>
```

`<div id="chartContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>`
Can anybody help me with this please ?

Comment: You code have problem, you cannot have to `div` with same `id` in one docuemt, because it may be cause to errors or another problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are using same ID on both div. Every element should have unique ID. Change that and try following :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function (){
       var dataSource = [
        { status: "Placed", outsideindia: 6.7, india: 28.6},
        { status: "Unplaced", unplaced: 9.6}
       ];

    $("#chartContainer1").dxChart({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        commonSeriesSettings: {
            argumentField: "status",
            type: "stackedBar"
        },

            </script>


                    <div id="chartContainer1" style="width: 100%; height: 440px;" ></div>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function ()  
                    {
       $("#chartContainer2").dxChart({


        series: {
            argumentField: "st_status",
            valueField: "oranges",
            name: "Series 1",
            type: "bar",
            color: "blue"
        }
    });
    }

                );
            </script>


    <div id="chartContainer2" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear then content of your `div` you can use from this:

```
$('#yourDivID').empty();
```